# Swapping Min and Max int of an array [Java]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm supposed to make a static method named swap() that scans an array of integers that takes in the min and max and swaps them. So if max has an index of 0 and min index of 3, index[5] = [3] now and index [3] = [5] now. 
So the array is created by user inputs:

```
public static int[] readInputs(int arraySize) {
    System.out.print("What length is the array? ");
    arraySize = console.nextInt();
    int[] intArray = new int[arraySize]; 
    for (int i = 0; i <= intArray.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        userInput = console.nextInt();
        intArray[i] = userInput;
    }
    return intArray;
        } //end of readInputs()
```

I am supposed to make another static method that swaps the min and max called swap():

```
public static int[] swap(int[] intArray){
    for(int index = 0; index < intArray.length; index++){
        if (intArray[index] > max){
            max = intArray[index];
        } 
        if (intArray[index]<min) {
            min = intArray[index];
        }
    }
} //end of swap()
```

So far, I have it so it finds the min and max, but I'm stuck on how to swap.

Comment: Instead of saving the `max` and `min`, save the index of the maximum and minimum value.

Comment: @Manu Aren't I already doing that? Or am I just storing the value of the index?

Comment: @Shayd3 nope,  `max = intArray[index];` is the actual element.  If you want to save the index, `max = index;` (and of course max is and `int`)

Comment: @ryanyuyu ah! Ok. Thank you! Now I just need to figure out how to swap

Comment: What if there are couple of MINs or MAXs in the array?

Comment: I agrees with Denis - how should you handle duplicates? You would need a second loop over the array in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just store the indices of the minimum and the maximum.

**Code**

```
public static int[] swap(int[] array) {
    int minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
        if (array[i] < array[minIndex])
            minIndex = i;
        if (array[i] > array[maxIndex])
            maxIndex = i;
    }
    int t;
    if (maxIndex != minIndex) {
        t = array[minIndex];
        array[minIndex] = array[maxIndex];
        array[maxIndex] = t;
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i : swap(new int[]{1,4,5,8,2,10}))
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

**Output**

```
10
4
5
8
2
1
```

Comment: What if there are 2 tens or 2 ones in your example?

Comment: @cricket_007 the first encountered minimum and maximum will be swapped when the same elements are encountered.

Comment: Sure, I understand that, but based on the problem description, shouldn't all mins and maxes be swapped?

Comment: You can start your loop at 1.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thanks for the pointer. I have edited the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it! You just have to save the index of max and min value and then swap the values!

```
public static int[] swap(int[] intArray){
    int max = intArray[0], min = intArray[0], maxIndex = 0, minIndex = 0;
    for(int index = 1; index < intArray.length; index++){
        if (intArray[index] > max){
            max = intArray[index];
            maxIndex = index;
        } 
        if (intArray[index]<min) {
            min = intArray[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }
    intArray[maxIndex] = min;
    intArray[minIndex] = max;

    return intArray;
} //end of swap()
```